# How to fix Drupal commons 7.x-3 OgException

Tags: organic-groups, 7

Problem is fixed in new version commons 7.x-3.3-rc4
https://drupal.org/node/2067473

**Modules:**

1. Organic groups 7.x.2.3
2. Organic groups access control  7.x.2.3

**The content access permissions have been rebuilt.**

In OG field settings (as default)
User-User entity 
Group visibility Determine access to the group
Group            Determine if this should be a group

I created a Private group with "Joining requires an invitation"
trying to add a post to the group I get following exception:

> OgException: Cannot set visibility of node ID 13 as the group node of
>   type "user"  does not have the "Group visibility" field attached to
>   it.  in _og_access_verify_access_field_existence()  (line 250 of
>   srv/www/htdocs/commons7x33rc2/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/og/og_access/og_access.module).

The same happens with a Public group with "Any site member can contribute"

What is wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late maybe but...

...check answer #8 at Organic Groups issues place: https://drupal.org/node/2063479#comment-7882345

I've followed it and solved (at least apparently) the issue.

Hope it helps. Have a nice day!
hip